# How to maintain order of insertion in dictionary in python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have dictionary where I want to maintain order of insertion. How can I do that?

```
    nested_dict = {
        "name" :"Your Name",
        "age" : "Your Age",
        "contact" : {
            "Street" : "Your Street",
            "State" : "Your home state",
            "Phone" : "Your Phone Number"
        }
    }
    print(nested_dict)
```

This is the output I got from 1st try:
{'contact': {'Street': 'Your Street', 'State': 'Your home state', 'Phone': 'Your Phone Number'}, 'name': 'Your Name', 'age': 'Your Age'}

Output from 2nd try:
{'name': 'Your Name', 'contact': {'Street': 'Your Street', 'Phone': 'Your Phone Number', 'State': 'Your home state'}, 'age': 'Your Age'}

Comment: Ordered Dictionaries: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: After using Ordered Dictionaries,is nested_dict dictionary anymore?
Can I access it using key instead of using indices?